# Prospects of topological/anyon approach to QC

Tags: fault-tolerance, topological-quantum-computing, anyons

Given the recent articles/preprints by [Google](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05954-4) and [Quantinuum](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.03766) claiming implementation of braiding of non-Abelian anyons on a quantum processor, what is the likely impact of these findings, and specifically on the feasibility of topological quantum computing as a more quick route to fault-tolerant QC?

To be more specific, along the lines of the question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1794/4824), do these recent results from Google and Quantinuum weaken any of the $11$ objections in this answer over at MathOverFlow, [On mathematical arguments against Quantum computing](https://mathoverflow.net/a/302495/125783), particularly Gil Kalai's about decoherence always outpacing the fault-tolerance threshold?

$$$$

(1) https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-05954-4

(2) https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.03766

Comment: Related: [Does Google's error correction paper invalidate Gil Kalai's arguments?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30197/does-googles-error-correction-paper-invalidate-gil-kalais-arguments)